# Working with an specific region generated by BoundingBox

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have `n` regions generated by [`regionprops`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) with `'BoundingBox'` and `'Image'` properties.  I saved the data (`[x, y, Δx, Δy]`) from a specific region (14 for example) to `bb1` that I want to work on but first I need to understand the following code:

```
bb1=floor( Ic(14,1).BoundingBox );
I1bb1=I1( bb1(2):bb1(2)+bb1(4)-1 , bb1(1):bb1(1)+bb1(3)-1 ,:);
```

After that, also I want to understand the next code that it is from the same example:

```
I2=I1bb1.*repmat(  Ic(BB,1).Image , [1 1 3]);
```

Where `Ic` contains `n` regions generated by *BoundingBox*

Answer (score 0):

You have a 3D variable `I1` (I guess RGB image) and you wish to crop the boundingbox `Ic(14,1).BoundingBox` from it. That is, have a smaller 3D array that corresponds to the pixels inside the bounding box in image `I1`. To do this cropping you have these commands:

```
bb1=floor( Ic(14,1).BoundingBox );
```

First, you make sure the values `[x, y, w, h]` of the bounding box are integers and not sub-pixels so that you can use these values for indexing. Then, you can index into `I1` with the bounding box:

```
I1bb1=I1( bb1(2):bb1(2)+bb1(4)-1 , bb1(1):bb1(1)+bb1(3)-1 ,:);
```

For the rows of `I1bb1` you take the rows from `bb1(2)` (`y` value) to `y+w-1` which is `bb1(2)+bb1(4)-1`. Same for the columns from `x` to `x+h-1`.

For the third line of code, you have the property `Ic(14,1).Image`. This property is

> Returns a binary image (logical) of the same size as the bounding box of the region. The on pixels correspond to the region, and all other pixels are off.

Now you want `I2` to be the same size as the bounding box, but all pixels in the boundingbox not belonging to the object are set to `[0 0 0]` (all RGB values zero). Thus you convert `Ic(14,1).Image` from 2D binary mask to a 3D mask over three channels:

```
repmat(  Ic(BB,1).Image , [1 1 3])
```

Finally you element-wise multiply the "inflated" mask with the cropped image `I1bb1`:

```
I2=I1bb1.*repmat(  Ic(BB,1).Image , [1 1 3]);
```

---

You can achieve the same results with slightly more readable code:

```
Ibb1 = imcrop( I1, bb1 ); %// crop a bounding box from image 
I2 = bsxfun( @times, Ibb1, Ic(14,1).Image ); %// no need for repmat
```

Comment: Here's a follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558409/working-with-erosion-and-dilatation