# Working with erosion and dilatation

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

From the the previous link:

[Working with an specific region generated by BoundingBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36759827/working-with-an-specific-region-generated-by-boundingbox)

The following code is based on it

```
se = strel('disk',9);

p_mask=imerode(Ic(BB,1).Image,se);
k_mask=imdilate(p_mask,se);

Ipointer=I2.*repmat( k_mask , [1 1 3]);

figure,imshow(Ipointer)

Mch=Ic(BB,1).Image-k_mask;
Mbch=bwareaopen(Mch,3000);
Ichaplet=I2.*repmat( Mbch , [1 1 3]);
figure,imshow(Ichaplet)
```

And so, I do not understand it

Comment: what is your question? what is your input(s)? what are you trying to do? why isn't it working for you?

Comment: you should always provide your image if you have ask something about image processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

google is your friend. if you don't know what a function does, google matlab + its name and read the reference documentation.

se is your structure element. Here defined as a disk with radius 9
http://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/strel-class.html

Your binary image is eroded, then dilated (which is called Opening)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opening_(morphology)

Assuming white is considered foreground (I can only guess without your image) Opening will remove small white spots. Erosion shrink everything by nibbling around the contour. If you nibble enough you eat the hole object :) Dilation will resize those objects that have not been eroded completely. Dilation will add pixels around the contour.

bwareaopen will remove connected components smaller than 3000 pixels
http://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwareaopen.html

I'm sure you can figure out the rest on your own!

Comment: "bwareaopen will remove connected components SMALLER than 3000 pixels", not bigger ;-)